# estimate confidence interval for poisson process

Tags: python, poisson-process, pandas

I would like to know how I can estimate the confidence intervals for poisson process distributed variables.

I have a pandas dataframe with a column of trials and a column of successes. I want to check if the highest rate lies within the confidence interval of the other rows.

Lets say the highest rate is 25 successes per 350K trials so lambda = 0.0000714
In another row I have 4 successes in 90K trials so lamdba =  0.0000444

I want to know if 0.0000714 lies within the confidence interval of 0.0000444. I will always test if a larger rate lies within the confidence interval of a smaller rate so maybe a one sided test is more reliable.

The means are really small so I cannot use an approximation of the normal distribution.

I use Python with the Pandas module and can use the statsmodels module if this makes life easier.

Comment: Your words *success*  and *trial* make sense for a binomial
distribution but are unclear in the Poisson process context. Does
*trial* here stand for a unit of time and *success* stand for an
arrival of the process?

Comment: @Yves hi yes units of time and arrivals are another way of saying it. The binomial distribution is not applicable here since the arrivals are exponentially distributed.

Comment: You could have a look to the **exactci** CRAN R package by M.P. Fay.
It implements exact confidence intervals for the Poisson rate based on quantiles of $\chi^2$ distributions. References are given in the package manual.

Comment: @Yves, thanks for the answer however we work in Python is there such a method available in Python? Or is the code with the calculations available of this package?

Comment: Yes of course, CRAN R packages are open source.